# delphi: connecting to hosted mysql server over internet

Tags: mysql, delphi

What is the most secure and effecient method of connecting a Delphi program to a MySQL database hosted on an Apache server from my web hosting provider.

Ideas, hints or any information regarding the above, preferably using dbExpress with Delphi 2010 will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the details you've chosen to not disclose.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/configuring-for-ssl.html. Creating an SSL/SSH tunnel for your database component is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Well you cant connect directly because of the security issues but there are a couple,

- Write a web-service that catches the request and send back you the
  response.
- write a php script that gets the requests and gives back responses.
- if you are hosting on a windows server you can connect via VPN that
  will give you a direct sql connection and still be secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect directly MySQL Database. I recommend using FireDAC component.

**About FireDAC :**

FireDAC Multi-Device Data Access Library
Universal Enterprise Data Connectivity

FireDAC is a Universal Data Access library for developing applications for multiple devices, connected to enterprise databases. With its powerful universal architecture, FireDAC enables native high-speed direct access from Delphi and C++Builder to InterBase, SQLite, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, SQL Anywhere, Advantage DB, Firebird, Access, Informix, DataSnap and more.

[FireDAC Data Access Components](http://www.embarcadero.com/kr/products/rad-studio/firedac)

Also you can use MySQL Data Access Components (MyDAC or UniDAC) :

**About MyDAC Component:**

MySQL Data Access Components (MyDAC) is a library of components that provides direct access to MySQL from Delphi, C++Builder, Lazarus (and Free Pascal) on Windows, Mac OS X, iOS, Android, Linux, and FreeBSD for both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms. Applications based on MyDAC can connect directly to MySQL server or work through the MySQL client library. MyDAC is designed to help programmers develop faster and cleaner MySQL database applications.

[MySQL Data Access Components](http://www.devart.com/mydac/)

If you want connect MySQL with dbExpress (i don't recommend it)

You need dbexpress driver for MySQL dbxmys.dll and alos MySQL client library libmySQL.dll.

Comment: are you sure you can? because most web hosting providers block direct connections to their database, they only allow to connect to MySQL server from localhost (from inside the server)

Comment: I don't know your provider or the other providers. The main subject is delphi can connect remote mysql server or client. I have a mysql database hosted apache server i can connect it using delphi with FireDac. Best regards

Comment: yes Delphi can do this if the server is configured that way, but he said Web hosting server that means that it doesn't allow direct connections if it would it would have a serious security issue. well it all depends on server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I use MySQL as a remotely accessed DBMS from Go Daddy web hosting. Unidac is used to connect to the remote data set no problem.  I then use a signed VCL component based GUI on the client side.

The VCL based GUI blows the doors off all other web based applications (including .NET).  All the functionality of the Delphi application works flawlessly but I perform all DBMS functions to a remotely hosted MySQL database.  I really appreciate this combination of technologies that allows me to produce the most robust applications possible.